# CSS KeyFrame effects

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I want my elements to `fade in` then 2 lines comming out of the circle, one to the left and one to the right.
But All I can't get is: Everytime I try to make the lines show up, it shrinks the whole thing, I want to fix the circle in the middle then make the lines (container) start to "grow".
Already set it to absolute but didn't make it :\

Code Running: [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/Ghaleon/pen/GERwOB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that using `pseudo selector` `:before and :after` to create smooth `CSS3 animation` instead of adding different `class` for each elements,

```css
.container{
 width:200px;
 height:auto;
 text-align:center;
 position:relative;
 top:10px;
}
.container > span{
 display:block;
 position:relative;
}
.container:before{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 width:10px;
 height:10px;
 background:blue;
 z-index:9;
 top:-10px;
 border-radius:50%;
 animation:opt 2s ease forwards;
 opacity:0;
}
.container:after{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 width:10px;
 height:10px;
 background:blue;
 z-index:9;
 bottom:-12px;
 border-radius:50%;
 animation:opt 2s ease forwards;
 opacity:0;
}
@keyframes opt{
 from{
  opacity:0;
 }
 to{
  opacity:1;
 }
}
.container > span:before{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 width:0px;
 height:2px;
 background:#111;
 z-index:7;
 bottom:-10px;
 right:50%;
 transform:translate(0,-50%);
 transition:1s ease;
 animation:wdth 2s ease forwards 1s;
}
.container > span:after{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 width:0px;
 height:2px;
 background:#111;
 z-index:7;
 top:-5px;
 left:50%;
 transition:1s ease;
 animation:wdth 2s ease forwards 1s;
}
@keyframes wdth{
 from{
  width:0px;
 }
 to{
  width:50px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <span>Ghaleon Games</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro use pseudo selector.

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks a lot. What if I wanted that line grow to both sides of the circle? I'm trying to do it but cant make it.

Comment: Welcome @PlayHardGoPro :-), to grow line in both side, so for that just add right:50%  and translate that -50% and increase width in keyframes section, this align the line to center and increase the width in both direction.

Comment: Thanks, @frnt where exactly should I Add that?  There is already a right:50%.

Comment: Ohhh yeah. Thanks again, dude. You're amazing !